# How to have a custom table of contents in Google Play Books?

Tags: google-play-store, pdf, ebooks, google-play-books, uploads

I uploaded a big PDF book to my Google Play and I was wondering if there was a way to make my own table of contents for it ? Right now, the only item in the table is the beginning of the book...

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

You could edit the pdf changing the table of contents, either using adobe acrobat or some other, free, software.

Comment: Forgot to mention, the table of contents in the pdf file on my laptop is fine, there's one entry for each big part of the book, but the version uploaded on my google play has no entry